# How do I convert a Dictionary to a Lookup?

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, lookup

I have a Dictionary that has a signature: `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`. I'd like to convert it to a Lookup with a signature: `Lookup<int, string>`.

I tried:

```
Lookup<int, string> loginGroups = mapADToRole.ToLookup(ad => ad.Value, ad => ad.Key);
```

But that is not working so well.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use:

```
var lookup = dictionary.SelectMany(p => p.Value
                                         .Select(x => new { p.Key, Value = x}))
                       .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

(You could use `KeyValuePair` instead of an anonymous type - I mostly didn't for formatting reasons.)

It's pretty ugly, but it would work. Can you replace whatever code *created* the dictionary to start with though? That would probably be cleaner.

Comment: I think you mean: `Select(x => new { Key = p.Key, Value = x})`

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: No, I meant what I wrote. It should work just fine as it is - the `Key` property name is inferred.

Comment: Nice I never tried it :)

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your code :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Out of curiosity, why do you need the Value = x? Shouldn't that be ascertained automatically?

Comment: @dotnetN00b: Well, I *could* have just used `x`, and then used `pair.x` in the `ToLookup` call - but that was ugly. I *could* have named the lambda expression parameter `Value`, but that would have been confusing with the previous `pair.Value`. Hence the `x = Value` compromise. I tried a few alternatives :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: You said to "replace whatever code created the dictionary" - how to? I can't use yield return in combination with ILookup. I receive multiple Key->List<Value> (i.e. IGrouping<Key,Value>) in a loop, how to write a nice function which returns ILookup<Key,Value>?

Comment: @D.R.: I have no idea what the context is here. You're answering a question from a year and a half ago, and we don't know anything about your situation. I suspect you should ask a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291147/how-to-return-ilookup-directly-without-using-a-dictionary-ilookup-converter