# How to return ILookup directly (without using a Dictionary->ILookup converter)

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lookup, yield-return

(Converting a `Dictionary` to `ILookup` is not very nice:
[How do I convert a Dictionary to a Lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420228/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-lookup/) )

I want to have an interface for my container class with the following method:

```
ILookup<Type, Entry> Query ( IEnumerable<QueryClause> query );
```

Each query clause specifies which and how many (and some more details) of a special kind of Entry should be taken out of the underlying container.

My implementation currently looks something like this:

```
var result = new Dictionary<Type, List<Entry>>();

foreach(var clause in query)
{
    var clauseResult = FulfillClause(clause);
    result.Add(clause.Type, clauseResult);
}

return result.ToLookup(); // here it is
```

Is there any chance this method my return `ILookup` directly? Unfortunately it does not support `yield return`.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be using `yield return`, so it's hard to see how that's relevant... and you haven't told us anything about `query` or `FulfillClause`.

Comment: I would like to replace the result.Add line with yield return, however, that is not possible as C# does not support yield return for ILookup (only IEnumerable)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure why you have the dictionary in the first place.  Does this work for you?

```
return query.ToLookup(clause => clause.Type, clause => FullFillClause(clause));
```

<strike>It doesn't comply with the `ILookup<Type, Entry>` interface but neither does the code you provide so I can't be certain about what you actually want.</strike>

Here's attempt after re-reading the question:

```
return query.SelectMany(c => FulfillClause(c).Select(r => new {Type=c.Type, Result=r}))
            .ToLookup(o => o.Type, o => o.Result);
```

It's a translation of @JonSkeet's linked answer.

To test without knowing the details of all the types & methods, I used this:

```
Func<List<int>> f = () => new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
var query = new List<Type> {typeof (int), typeof (string)};

var l = query.SelectMany(t => f().Select(n => new {Type = t, Result = n}))
    .ToLookup(o => o.Type, o => o.Result);
```

---

If you control all the code, you could restructure some of it to enhance readability:

```
return query.SelectMany(c => c.Fulfill())
            .ToLookup(res => res.Type, res => res.Value);

...
// You will need to create the ClauseFulfillment type yourself
public IEnumerable<ClauseFulfillment> FulFill()
{
   var results = // whatever FulfillClause does
   foreach(var r in results)
      yield return new ClauseFulfillment {Type = Type, Result = r}; 
}
```

Comment: Why does my code not comply with the ILookup<Type, Entry> interface? Given the dictionary and the ToLookup extension method given in the linked thread I fulfill the interface.

Comment: Please take a look at the linked thread, thank you. It shows an extension method which conveerts Dictionary<K, List<V>> into Lookup<K, V>.

Comment: Thank you for your big effort! +1! However, I'm not so sure if the new code is really more readable than my original effort. Thank you anyways. I was hoping C# allows me to do some yield return stuff :-)

Comment: @D.R. -- you're welcome!  If you control all the code, I've updated my answer.